# How to install smart assembly in docker container

Tags: asp.net, .net, docker, obfuscation, smartassembly

I have deployed and hosted my .net application in Docker Container. Now I wanted to apply obfuscation over my code using smart assembly to secure my code.
So, just wanted to know is there any way how we can achieve code obfuscation in docker using Smart assembly?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The same way you'd do it outside of docker.

Comment: A commercial product might not allow you to install it inside Docker. And since you only need to deploy the compiled binaries to an image, the actual obfuscation can be done on your local machine. Contact the vendor for more guidance please.